# Restrict the execution of same GORM object in groovy

Tags: hibernate, groovy, grails-orm

I' am new in groovy.in my project I get the data from db using GORM object. When Ever I call the object for data it execute multiple time.I have no Idea why it is executing. After getting the data using the same object when I see the hibernate log there is more then execution of the same object.

for example :

```
Country country = Country.findByCountryCode('all');
```

if I call the above object get the following log in hibernate

```
    Hibernate: select * from ( select this_.id as id1_79_0_, this_.version as version2_79_0_, this_.admin_instructions_for_use_id as admin_instructions3_79_0_, this_.admin_faq_id as admin_faq_id4_79_0_, this_.contact as contact5_79_0_, this_.country_id as country_id6_79_0_, this_.date_display_format as date_display_forma7_79_0_, this_.default_language as default_language8_79_0_, this_.distributors_id as distributors_id9_79_0_, this_.ecko_faq_id as ecko_faq_id10_79_0_, this_.ecos_faq_id as ecos_faq_id11_79_0_, this_.features_id as features_id12_79_0_, this_.footer_logo_left_id as footer_logo_left_13_79_0_, this_.footer_logo_right_id as footer_logo_right14_79_0_, this_.instructions_for_use_id as instructions_for_15_79_0_, this_.language_id as language_id16_79_0_, this_.license_agreement_id as license_agreement17_79_0_, this_.name_display_format as name_display_form18_79_0_, this_.participate as participate19_79_0_, this_.terms_of_use_id as terms_of_use_id20_79_0_, this_.use_default_format as use_default_forma21_79_0_, this_.user_guide_id as user_guide_id22_79_0_ from country_configuration this_ where this_.country_id=? and this_.language_id=? ) where rownum <= ?
    Hibernate: select * from ( select this_.id as id1_79_0_, this_.version as version2_79_0_, this_.admin_instructions_for_use_id as admin_instructions3_79_0_, this_.admin_faq_id as admin_faq_id4_79_0_, this_.contact as contact5_79_0_, this_.country_id as country_id6_79_0_, this_.date_display_format as date_display_forma7_79_0_, this_.default_language as default_language8_79_0_, this_.distributors_id as distributors_id9_79_0_, this_.ecko_faq_id as ecko_faq_id10_79_0_, this_.ecos_faq_id as ecos_faq_id11_79_0_, this_.features_id as features_id12_79_0_, this_.footer_logo_left_id as footer_logo_left_13_79_0_, this_.footer_logo_right_id as footer_logo_right14_79_0_, this_.instructions_for_use_id as instructions_for_15_79_0_, this_.language_id as language_id16_79_0_, this_.license_agreement_id as license_agreement17_79_0_, this_.name_display_format as name_display_form18_79_0_, this_.participate as participate19_79_0_, this_.terms_of_use_id as terms_of_use_id20_79_0_, this_.use_default_format as use_default_forma21_79_0_, this_.user_guide_id as user_guide_id22_79_0_ from country_configuration this_ where this_.country_id=? and this_.language_id=? ) where rownum <= ?
    Hibernate: select * from ( select this_.id as id1_79_0_, this_.version as version2_79_0_, this_.admin_instructions_for_use_id as admin_instructions3_79_0_, this_.admin_faq_id as admin_faq_id4_79_0_, this_.contact as contact5_79_0_, this_.country_id as country_id6_79_0_, this_.date_display_format as date_display_forma7_79_0_, this_.default_language as default_language8_79_0_, this_.distributors_id as distributors_id9_79_0_, this_.ecko_faq_id as ecko_faq_id10_79_0_, this_.ecos_faq_id as ecos_faq_id11_79_0_, this_.features_id as features_id12_79_0_, this_.footer_logo_left_id as footer_logo_left_13_79_0_, this_.footer_logo_right_id as footer_logo_right14_79_0_, this_.instructions_for_use_id as instructions_for_15_79_0_, this_.language_id as language_id16_79_0_, this_.license_agreement_id as license_agreement17_79_0_, this_.name_display_format as name_display_form18_79_0_, this_.participate as participate19_79_0_, this_.terms_of_use_id as terms_of_use_id20_79_0_, this_.use_default_format as use_default_forma21_79_0_, this_.user_guide_id as user_guide_id22_79_0_ from country_configuration this_ where this_.country_id=? and this_.language_id=? ) where rownum <= ?
    Hibernate: select * from ( select this_.id as id1_79_0_, this_.version as version2_79_0_, this_.admin_instructions_for_use_id as admin_instructions3_79_0_, this_.admin_faq_id as admin_faq_id4_79_0_, this_.contact as contact5_79_0_, this_.country_id as country_id6_79_0_, this_.date_display_format as date_display_forma7_79_0_, this_.default_language as default_language8_79_0_, this_.distributors_id as distributors_id9_79_0_, this_.ecko_faq_id as ecko_faq_id10_79_0_, this_.ecos_faq_id as ecos_faq_id11_79_0_, this_.features_id as features_id12_79_0_, this_.footer_logo_left_id as footer_logo_left_13_79_0_, this_.footer_logo_right_id as footer_logo_right14_79_0_, this_.instructions_for_use_id as instructions_for_15_79_0_, this_.language_id as language_id16_79_0_, this_.license_agreement_id as license_agreement17_79_0_, this_.name_display_format as name_display_form18_79_0_, this_.participate as participate19_79_0_, this_.terms_of_use_id as terms_of_use_id20_79_0_, this_.use_default_format as use_default_forma21_79_0_, this_.user_guide_id as user_guide_id22_79_0_ from country_configuration this_ where this_.country_id=? and this_.language_id=? ) where rownum <= ?
Hibernate: select * from ( select this_.id as id1_79_0_, this_.version as version2_79_0_, this_.admin_instructions_for_use_id as admin_instructions3_79_0_, this_.admin_faq_id as admin_faq_id4_79_0_, this_.contact as contact5_79_0_, this_.country_id as country_id6_79_0_, this_.date_display_format as date_display_forma7_79_0_, this_.default_language as default_language8_79_0_, this_.distributors_id as distributors_id9_79_0_, this_.ecko_faq_id as ecko_faq_id10_79_0_, this_.ecos_faq_id as ecos_faq_id11_79_0_, this_.features_id as features_id12_79_0_, this_.footer_logo_left_id as footer_logo_left_13_79_0_, this_.footer_logo_right_id as footer_logo_right14_79_0_, this_.instructions_for_use_id as instructions_for_15_79_0_, this_.language_id as language_id16_79_0_, this_.license_agreement_id as license_agreement17_79_0_, this_.name_display_format as name_display_form18_79_0_, this_.participate as participate19_79_0_, this_.terms_of_use_id as terms_of_use_id20_79_0_, this_.use_default_format as use_default_forma21_79_0_, this_.user_guide_id as user_guide_id22_79_0_ from country_configuration this_ where this_.country_id=? and this_.language_id=? ) where rownum <= ?
    Hibernate: select * from ( select this_.id as id1_79_0_, this_.version as version2_79_0_, this_.admin_instructions_for_use_id as admin_instructions3_79_0_, this_.admin_faq_id as admin_faq_id4_79_0_, this_.contact as contact5_79_0_, this_.country_id as country_id6_79_0_, this_.date_display_format as date_display_forma7_79_0_, this_.default_language as default_language8_79_0_, this_.distributors_id as distributors_id9_79_0_, this_.ecko_faq_id as ecko_faq_id10_79_0_, this_.ecos_faq_id as ecos_faq_id11_79_0_, this_.features_id as features_id12_79_0_, this_.footer_logo_left_id as footer_logo_left_13_79_0_, this_.footer_logo_right_id as footer_logo_right14_79_0_, this_.instructions_for_use_id as instructions_for_15_79_0_, this_.language_id as language_id16_79_0_, this_.license_agreement_id as license_agreement17_79_0_, this_.name_display_format as name_display_form18_79_0_, this_.participate as participate19_79_0_, this_.terms_of_use_id as terms_of_use_id20_79_0_, this_.use_default_format as use_default_forma21_79_0_, this_.user_guide_id as user_guide_id22_79_0_ from country_configuration this_ where this_.country_id=? and this_.language_id=? ) where rownum <= ?
```

Please any one guide me to fix this.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are the bindings the same for all of those queries?

Comment: Yes Mike. All are the same bindings for that single query.This is the example, the queries same way most of the executing in application. Can you help me to fix this?